# The c++ difference behavior when multiplying int and long type in Visual studio 2013 and g++ 7.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, int, g++, long-integer

The following same code snippet will produce different values in  Visual studio 2013 and  g++ 7.1

```
long test_1 = 631094;
int test_2 = 4107;

test_1 = test_1 * test_2;

cout << test_1 << endl;
```

Vs2013 will get overflow : -1703064238

g++ 7.1 will get the correct : 2591903058

What reason can be explained to these strange issue in difference ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: what's `sizeof(long)` in the two compilers?

Comment: I suggest you to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models Basicly in windows long is 32 bits and in unix it is 64 bits

Comment: it probably depends on the compilation mode. if vs is 32 bit and g++ is 64, than you would get it. Make sure that both compilers run in 64-bit mode. Other than lower 32 bits of both values are absolutely identical in both cases. And you can also try 'long long' (double long) instead of the single one.

Comment: To All above: Thank you for the explanation and I think you are right

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the encoding format of the `long` type.

The only requirement is that a minimal range must be catered for and that it be at least as "wide" as `int`.

So it's quite possible that it may be the *same size* as an `int` and, if you have a two's complement 16-bit `int` type, you'll see the overflow case. If your `long` type is 32 bits (for example), there'll be no overflow.

The best way to discover this is to simply print out the relative sizes of those two types, with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Size of long is " << sizeof(long) << ".\n";
    std::cout << "Size of int  is " << sizeof(int)  << ".\n";
}
```